# How to sort data in Vuex state with mutation

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, vuex, mutation

I have an array of objects that displays in a table on my html page in one of my Vue components. The array of objects is data in the state of a Vuex store.

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        jobs: [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]
    },
    mutations: {
        sortJobs(state, sortKey) {
            console.log('running mutation');
            let compare = 0;
            this.state.jobs.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
                    compare = 1;
                } else if (b.sortKey > a.sortKey) {
                    compare = -1;
                }
                return compare;
            });
        }
    },
    getters: {
        jobs: state => state.jobs
    }
});
```

I am trying to sort the array of objects in the mutation `sortJobs`, but it will not work. I am calling the mutation in one of my components.

```
methods: {
    sortBy: function(sortKey) {
        this.$store.commit('sortJobs', sortKey);
    }
}
```

This will not change the order of the array of objects, nor in my table. I've tested to see if I can do anything to the array of objects, and when I replace `this.state.jobs.sort(...)` with `this.state.jobs.shift();`, the first object element in the array disappears off of my table. But when it comes to sorting, I can't get this to sort at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're sorting `state.replenJobs`, not `state.jobs`. This will sort `state.replenJobs` in place (which I don't see in your sample code) and leave `state.jobs` untouched.

Comment: @ebbishop That's my mistake. That's a typo. `replenJobs` is supposed to say `jobs`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arrays are tricky in Vue.  Take a look at these [common gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/).

Instead of mutating the array in place, try making a copy, sorting the copy and setting `state.jobs` to that sorted array.

Something like this:

```
  mutations: {
    sortJobs(state, sortKey) {
        console.log('running mutation');
        const jobs = this.state.jobs;
        jobs.sort((a, b) => {
            let compare = 0;
            if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
                compare = 1;
            } else if (b[sortKey] > a[sortKey]) {
                compare = -1;
            }
            return compare;
        });
        state.jobs = jobs;
    }
  },
```

Also:

- move the instantiation of the compare variable into the sort callback, so it'll be new each time you sort two list items.
- instead of using `a.sortKey`, which will literally look for the `sortKey` property, use `a[sortKey]`, which will let you access a variable attribute.

Working example, without vuex:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/7eku4vf0/

Comment: !!!!
This was kind of what I needed. Really, what it was was I was trying to reference the sort key parameter as `a.sortKey` and `b.sortKey`, when it should have really been `a[sortKey]` and `b[sortKey]`. The function was probably literally trying to sort by a field named "sortKey". I guess my follow up question would be why that is, and what the notation for a[sortKey] (brackets) is called. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't think `const jobs = this.state.jobs;` is making a copy, though. You're just making a local reference to the same array. That is, `state.jobs ===  jobs` even before the `state.jobs = jobs` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on @Ebbishops Answer you can modify this further by checking your current sort direction like so:

```
// html
<th scope="col" @click="sort('title')">Title</th>
<th scope="col" @click="sort('content')">Content</th>

// script
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['articles/SORT_ARTICLES']),
        sort(s) {
          this.$store.dispatch('articles/' + 'SORT_ARTICLES', s)
        }
      },


// state
export const state = () => ({
  articles: {},
  currentSort: 'title',
  currentSortDir: 'asc',
});


//mutations
  SET_SORT_ARTICLES: (state, sortKey) => {
    if(sortKey === state.currentSort) {
      state.currentSortDir = state.currentSortDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    }
    state.currentSort = sortKey;

      state.articles.sort((a,b) => {
        let modifier = 1;
        if(state.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
        if(a[state.currentSort] < b[state.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
        if(a[state.currentSort] > b[state.currentSort]) return modifier;
        return state.articles;
      });
  },
```

this allows you to sort in both directions

Comment: is `articles: {}` an object instead of an array here?